# Can anyone identify this BMX frame?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Can anyone identify this BMX bike frame please?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles SE! In order to realistically help you out, can you provide better photos of the frame and add it to your post using the [edit](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/91768/edit) function? Any other information and detail shots of badging etc. will help. _Serial numbers_ will not. In this form, I'm afraid, your question will get flagged/closed because it lacks information to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: That is a pretty unique down tube. That could help narrow down a manufacturer, if not even a model.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a [Sunday Bikes](https://sundaybikes.com/technology/wave-down-tube/) frame.
With just one picture it's impossible to verify the other things that would positively identify the frame.

[image]

According to the advertising:

> Down tube dents are common with our competitor’s frames and they significantly weaken the front end of your bike. Our double-butted, 1.45″ diameter down-tube feature our proven Wave shaping to fight denting against contact made from a rail, ledge, coping and whatever else happens to get thrown at it.
> Take your hand and run it along the underside of one of our frames with Wave tubing. You will no doubt notice all the ridges.
> The tighter radius of the waves stiffens the tube making it harder to dent. While it’s not able to eliminate every dent, it will take far more abuse than a non-Wave down-tube. Important to note is that it adds minimal weight compared to a traditional tube.

Comment: Judging by BB shape this is fairly old, but even the oldest Sunday frames have stamped Sunday on the rear dropouts so I'm guessing OP would see that. And the BB nor chainstay shape match Sunday, see e.g. https://sundaybikes.com/history/. No idea what it would be instead though, not enough information..